# JQUERY ToolTip - Styling Specific Words

Tags: php, jquery, css, styles

I have this jquery:

```
this.tooltip = function(){  
    /* CONFIG */        
        xOffset = 10;
        yOffset = 20;       
        // these 2 variable determine popup's distance from the cursor
        // you might want to adjust to get the right result     
    /* END CONFIG */        
    $("a.tooltip").hover(function(e){                                             
        this.t = this.title;
        this.title = "";                                      
        $("body").append("<p id='tooltip'>"+ this.t +"</p>");
        $("#tooltip")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
            .fadeIn("fast");        
    },
    function(){
        this.title = this.t;        
        $("#tooltip").remove();
    }); 
    $("a.tooltip").mousemove(function(e){
        $("#tooltip")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
    });         
};



// starting the script on page load
$(document).ready(function(){
    tooltip();
});
```

Which is used with a CSS Class called "tooltip" which has `font-variant:small-caps;` in it.

All tooltips are in small-caps and look great :)

The tooltip is called like this :
`<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="this is the tooltip">hover to see tooltip</a>`

I would like to have one or two words in the tooltip BOLD and all lowercase..
How can I do that with out upsetting the reset of the tooltips ?

So instead of displaying as :

THIS IS THE TOOLTIP

I'd like :

this is THE TOOLTIP

Any ideas ??

Answer (score 0):

You can add a certain class to the text that you're adding, and then style it via CSS. 
For example

```
$("a.tooltip").hover(function(e){                                             
        this.t = this.title;
        this.title = "";                                      
        $("body").append("<p id='tooltip' class='tooltipText'>"+ this.t +"</p>");
        $("#tooltip")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
            .fadeIn("fast");        
    },
```

And then the css:

```
.tooltipText
{
   text-transform: uppercase;
   /* any style you want  */

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. But I'm not sure that is what I need.

I want to make a few words within the original tooltip a different case, compared to the rest of the tooltip. How do I do that ?

Comment: Then you will need a function to recognize the words you need to change it's case, depending on the result you wish to get. What is the criteria for this differentiation?